# Check if genvar is odd in verilog

Tags: verilog

I am new to verilog hdl, I would like to know how to write the following code right:

```
genvar cnt;
for( cnt = 0 ; cnt < 5 ; cnt = cnt + 1) begin
   if (cnt is odd) begin
     // do something
    end else begin
    // do something else
      end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use the modulus operator (`%`):

```
if (cnt % 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd need to do this in verilog. Verilog is an hardware description language not just another programming language.

To check if `cnt` is odd I suggest you just check the last bit of the variable.

If the last bit is `1` the number will be odd.

```
if (cnt[0]) begin
    //cnt is odd
    //do something
end else begin
    //cnt is even
    //do something else
end
```

Comment: *"I'm not sure why you'd need to do this in Verilog"* I use the exact same code to implement odd/even sort. "Ours is not to wonder why" (The Charge of the Light Brigade by Alfred Tennyson)